# Where can a Grafana datasource's query options be modified?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I want to add more text fields under the "Query Options" here for my datasource. But in the datasource code, I don’t see where this is specified. Searching for “Regex” in the datasource codebase doesn’t return anything. I generated the datasource using the starter code from grafana-toolkit. Which file do I add the text fields to?

[image]

I tried adding an extra field to the `QueryEditor.tsx` file, but it doesn't show up on this page.